# Does TTFB refers to loading a webpage totally or just until fold?

Tags: ttfb, above-the-fold

Does TTFB refers to loading a webpage totally or just until fold?

By fold I mean to the fold as in "Render blocking Above-The-Fold content".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TTFB stands for "Time To First Byte", and it refers to the time between when the request is sent and the time that the *first byte* of the response is received.

This happens before the page is loaded, before the fold is loaded, before any content whatsoever is loaded, because the "first byte" refers to the very beginning of the content.